Flask streaming chat Interface
I’m trying to make a Flask interface for an assistant I have created via the OpenAI API.
The assistant is setup correctly and streams output to a console perfectly. However, I am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to set up a Flask-app to stream the output for the chat bot correctly.
Does anyone have any examples of a Flask-interface with streaming that I could follow?
Here is the code that I have. It is working, but the streaming functionality is not. Instead of posting a chunk every time the assistant output is updated, it only posts chunks when the buffer limit is reached (several hundread words). Additionally, I have no idea how to integrate the streaming output into a typical chat-interface that shows the last few back-and-forths.
@main.route('/chat_stream', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def chat_stream():
# the chat_session contains assistant_id, thread, and client instances
chat_session = current_app.config['chat_session']

# using the stock event handler suggested here; https://platform.openai.com/docs/assistants/quickstart
handler = EventHandler()

# fixed input for now
user_input = 'please write a 100 word poem'

# create a new message
message = chat_session.client.beta.threads.messages.create(
    thread_id=chat_session.thread.id,
    role='user',
    content=user_input
)

# streaming functionality does not work 
@stream_with_context
def generate():
    try:
        with chat_session.client.beta.threads.runs.stream(
                thread_id=chat_session.thread.id,
                assistant_id=chat_session.assistant_id,
                instructions='system_prompt',
                event_handler=EventHandler(),
        ) as stream:
            for chunk in stream:
                if type(chunk) == openai.types.beta.assistant_stream_event.ThreadMessageDelta:
                    yield str(chunk.data.delta.content[0].text.value)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error during streaming: {e}")
        yield f"Error: {e}"

return Response(generate(), content_type='text/plain')

